# Computation on subset of columns called by `..` in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use a function on a subset of columns in a `data.table`. For example, I might want to create a new variable which is the maximum value in all columns that contain the string ".line" of the datatable

```
set.seed(1)
dtX <- data.table(
  "x.unit" = rnorm(10,0,1),
  "y.line" = rnorm(10,0,1),
  "z.line" = rnorm(10,0,1))
```

I can do this by specifying the columns manually:

```
dtX[, maxVal := max(c(y.line,z.line)), by = 1:10]
```

But in my real data I have a lot of columns with long and complex names; I'd like to avoid writing them all out manually. I have a vector of my focal columns (`focalCol`) and would have thought I can use `..` to refer to those but I am getting "type" error (type on RHS != type of LHS, see notes below).

```
focalCols <- colnames(dtX)[grepl(".line" , colnames(dtX))]
dtX[, maxVal := max(..focalCols), by = 1:10]
```

**Is there a `data.table`-way that I can reference to a vector of columns in a `data.table` to perform computation?**

---

Note, the error code:

```
Type of RHS ('character') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.SDcols` to specify selected columns

```
library(data.table)

focalCols <- grep('\\.line', names(dtX), value = TRUE)
#Or
#focalCols <- colnames(dtX)[grepl(".line" , colnames(dtX))]

dtX[, maxVal := max(.SD), .SDcols = focalCols, by = 1:nrow(dtX)]
dtX

#    x.unit  y.line  z.line  maxVal
# 1: -0.626  1.5118  0.9190  1.5118
# 2:  0.184  0.3898  0.7821  0.7821
# 3: -0.836 -0.6212  0.0746  0.0746
# 4:  1.595 -2.2147 -1.9894 -1.9894
# 5:  0.330  1.1249  0.6198  1.1249
# 6: -0.820 -0.0449 -0.0561 -0.0449
# 7:  0.487 -0.0162 -0.1558 -0.0162
# 8:  0.738  0.9438 -1.4708  0.9438
# 9:  0.576  0.8212 -0.4782  0.8212
#10: -0.305  0.5939  0.4179  0.5939
```

As mentioned by @chinsoon12 a faster alternative would be to use `max.col` and do matrix subsetting of values instead of grouping by each row.

```
dtX[, maxVal := as.matrix(.SD)[cbind(seq_len(.N), max.col(.SD))], .SDcols = focalCols]
```

Comment: and also a faster version: `dtX[, maxVal := as.matrix(.SD)[cbind(seq_len(.N), max.col(.SD))], .SDcols = focalCols]`